# sum of even numbers in Fibonacci sequence

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function to calculate the sum of only even numbers  in Fibonacci sequence. How can I make  this if/while loop to work?.

```
function fib() {
  var x, y, total;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      x = 1;
      y = 2;
    }

    while( x % 2) {
      total = x + y;
      x = y;
      y = total;
    }

    return(total);
  }
};
```

Comment: Flagged because.. this isn't a question

Comment: @ Enjoy Turtles, Thanks I fixed it and turned it into a question. I very new here and need to learn the system.

Comment: Notice Fibonacci sequences are infinite, and there is none containing only odd numbers. Just `return Infinity` will work better than any loop.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  let a = 1,
    b = 1,
    acc = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < num - 2; i++) {
    let c = a;

    a += b;
    b = c;

    if (a % 2 === 0) {
      acc += a;
    }
  }

  return acc;
}

console.log(sumFibs(10)); // Logs out the even sum of the first 10 fabonacci sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while(x % 2)` with `while(x % 2 === 0)`.  You're checking if `x % 2` is true in your original while loop.